# Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong with my table?

Tags: tables, arrays

I got the error !Package array Error: Illegal prem-token (o): `c' used. Don't know how to solve this problem. My table has only one row.

```
\begin{equation}        
                \xi = \left\{\begin{array}
                       {cols}X\\Y\\\varphi\\v_x\\v_y\\\omega\end{array}\right\},
                  u = \left\{\begin{array}{cols}$D$\\\delta\end{array}\right\}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: There seems to be a mismatch between the title and first paragraph of your write-up, with refer to a "table" that consists of a single *row*, and the code, which employs 2 `array` environments which contain one column vector each. Please clarify and/or edit your posting as needed.

Answer (score 1):

The two instances of the statement

```
\begin{array}{cols}
```

are not syntactically valid: LaTeX knows about the `c` and `l` column types, but nothing about column types called `o` and `s`.

Since the bodies of the two `array` environments appear to be column vectors, you should be writing

```
\begin{array}{c}
```

in both instances.